# Failed to download realm core file

Tags: react-native, realm

I add realm to my react native application. It had an error with react native framework. So I changed to ReactJS.framework. But It freezed for 2 minutes and failed. How can I solve this problem? First time  I thought it caused by firewall of company. But there are other reasons. Because I already to declare proxy configuration in the shell script.

```
Build target RealmJS static of project RealmJS with configuration Debug

PhaseScriptExecution Download\ Core /Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS\ static.build/Script-F63FF2C51C12462600B3B8E0.sh
    cd /Users/jouk/Workspace/react-native-todo/react-native-todo/mobileOpenAlm/node_modules/realm
    export ACTION=build
    export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
    export ALTERNATE_GROUP=staff
    export ALTERNATE_MODE=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export ALTERNATE_OWNER=jouk
    export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS=NO
    export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS=NO
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/AppleInternal/Developer
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR=/AppleInternal
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/AppleInternal/Documentation
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/AppleInternal/Library
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
    export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES=NO
    export ARCHS=x86_64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD="i386 x86_64"
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT="i386 x86_64"
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT=i386
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT=x86_64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT="i386 x86_64"
    export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS="watchos iphonesimulator macosx appletvsimulator watchsimulator appletvos iphoneos"
    export BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=marker
    export BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY=YES
    export BUILD_COMPONENTS="headers build"
    export BUILD_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products
    export BUILD_ROOT=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products
    export BUILD_STYLE=
    export BUILD_VARIANTS=normal
    export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    export CACHE_ROOT=/var/folders/ps/1gryfyj54h3gp1z2gktm0c9w0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode
    export CCHROOT=/var/folders/ps/1gryfyj54h3gp1z2gktm0c9w0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode
    export CHMOD=/bin/chmod
    export CHOWN=/usr/sbin/chown
    export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=c++14
    export CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++
    export CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES=YES
    export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC=YES
    export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation
    export CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE=YES_ERROR
    export CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION=YES
    export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS=YES_ERROR
    export CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE=YES
    export CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH=YES
    export CLASS_FILE_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/JavaClasses"
    export CLEAN_PRECOMPS=YES
    export CLONE_HEADERS=NO
    export CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRealmJS.a
    export CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
    export CODE_SIGN_CONTEXT_CLASS=XCiPhoneSimulatorCodeSignContext
    export COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS=NO
    export COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES=NO
    export COMMAND_MODE=legacy
    export COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS=/var/folders/ps/1gryfyj54h3gp1z2gktm0c9w0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/7.2.1-7C1002/Xcode/CompositeSDKs
    export COMPRESS_PNG_FILES=YES
    export CONFIGURATION=Debug
    export CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    export CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
    export COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA=NO
    export COPY_HEADERS_RUN_UNIFDEF=NO
    export COPY_PHASE_STRIP=NO
    export COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS=YES
    export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_PLATFORM_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
    export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME=iphoneos
    export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk
    export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_SDK_NAME=iphoneos9.2
    export CP=/bin/cp
    export CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY=NO
    export CURRENT_ARCH=x86_64
    export CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=0.10.0
    export CURRENT_VARIANT=normal
    export DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING=NO
    export DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES
    export DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf
    export DEFAULT_COMPILER=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export DEFAULT_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export DEFINES_MODULE=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_ENV_NAME=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_NAME=mios-simulator-version-min
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_PREFIX=-mios-simulator-version-min=
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
    export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SUGGESTED_VALUES="6.0 6.1 7.0 7.1 8.0 8.1 8.2 8.3 8.4 9.0 9.1 9.2"
    export DERIVED_FILES_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/DerivedSources"
    export DERIVED_FILE_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/DerivedSources"
    export DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/DerivedSources"
    export DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
    export DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
    export DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE=English
    export DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM=NO
    export DSTROOT=/tmp/RealmJS.dst
    export DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME=libRealmJS.a.dSYM
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT=NO
    export DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    export EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME=-iphonesimulator
    export EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=NO
    export EMBED_ASSET_PACKS_IN_PRODUCT_BUNDLE=NO
    export ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
    export ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES=NO
    export ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND=YES
    export ENABLE_TESTABILITY=YES
    export EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS=".DS_Store .svn .git .hg CVS"
    export EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES="*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch *.xcode* *.xcassets (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
    export EXECUTABLE_EXTENSION=a
    export EXECUTABLE_NAME=libRealmJS.a
    export EXECUTABLE_PATH=libRealmJS.a
    export EXECUTABLE_PREFIX=lib
    export EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX=.a
    export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=
    export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME=
    export EXPANDED_PROVISIONING_PROFILE=
    export FILE_LIST="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/Objects/LinkFileList"
    export FIXED_FILES_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/FixedFiles"
    export FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX=-framework
    export FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "
    export FRAMEWORK_VERSION=A
    export FULL_PRODUCT_NAME=libRealmJS.a
    export GCC3_VERSION=3.3
    export GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=gnu99
    export GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC=NO
    export GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=NO
    export GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS=YES
    export GCC_OBJC_LEGACY_DISPATCH=YES
    export GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=0
    export GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS="c objective-c c++ objective-c++"
    export GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="DEBUG=1 REALM_HAVE_CONFIG __ASSERTMACROS__"
    export GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN=NO
    export GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=NO
    export GCC_VERSION=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export GCC_VERSION_IDENTIFIER=com_apple_compilers_llvm_clang_1_0
    export GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION=YES
    export GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE=YES_ERROR
    export GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR=YES
    export GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS=YES_AGGRESSIVE
    export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION=YES
    export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE=YES
    export GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE=NO
    export GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE=NO
    export GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export GID=20
    export GROUP=staff
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_FRAMEWORK_PREFIX_ENTRIES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_VFS=NO
    export HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include  /Users/jouk/Workspace/react-native-todo/react-native-todo/mobileOpenAlm/node_modules/realm/vendor/PEGTL /Users/jouk/Workspace/react-native-todo/react-native-todo/mobileOpenAlm/node_modules/realm/vendor"
    export HIDE_BITCODE_SYMBOLS=YES
    export HOME=/Users/jouk
    export ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv
    export INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS=YES
    export INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT=binary
    export INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS=NO
    export INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/RealmJS.dst/usr/local/lib
    export INSTALL_GROUP=staff
    export INSTALL_MODE_FLAG=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export INSTALL_OWNER=jouk
    export INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/lib
    export INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/RealmJS.dst
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS="-J-Xms64m -J-XX:NewSize=4M -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
    export JAVA_APP_STUB=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES=YES
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE=JAR
    export JAVA_COMPILER=/usr/bin/javac
    export JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS=Resources
    export JAVA_JAR_FLAGS=cv
    export JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR=.
    export JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS=-urg
    export JIKES_DEFAULT_FLAGS="+E +OLDCSO"
    export KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS=NO
    export LD_DEPENDENCY_INFO_FILE="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RealmJS_dependency_info.dat"
    export LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE=NO
    export LD_MAP_FILE_PATH="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/RealmJS-LinkMap-normal-x86_64.txt"
    export LD_NO_PIE=NO
    export LD_QUOTE_LINKER_ARGUMENTS_FOR_COMPILER_DRIVER=YES
    export LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
    export LEX=lex
    export LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE=YES
    export LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX=-l
    export LIBRARY_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Extensions
    export LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator core"
    export LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES=NO
    export LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_x86_64="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RealmJS.LinkFileList"
    export LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES
    export LOCALIZABLE_CONTENT_DIR=
    export LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export LOCAL_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Library/Developer
    export LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/Library
    export LOCROOT=
    export LOCSYMROOT=
    export MACH_O_TYPE=staticlib
    export MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=15C50
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL=101102
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR=101100
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR=1102
    export MODULE_CACHE_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
    export MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO=YES
    export NATIVE_ARCH=i386
    export NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT=i386
    export NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT=x86_64
    export NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL=x86_64
    export NO_COMMON=YES
    export OBJC_ABI_VERSION=2
    export OBJECT_FILE_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/Objects"
    export OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/Objects-normal"
    export OBJROOT=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates
    export ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
    export OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL=0
    export OS=MACOS
    export OSAC=/usr/bin/osacompile
    export OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS=" -isystem core/include"
    export PACKAGE_TYPE=com.apple.package-type.static-library
    export PASCAL_STRINGS=YES
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES="/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Headers /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
    export PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS="c++ objective-c++"
    export PKGINFO_FILE_PATH="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/PkgInfo"
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Tools
    export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr
    export PLATFORM_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
    export PLATFORM_DISPLAY_NAME="iOS Simulator"
    export PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator
    export PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH=x86_64
    export PLATFORM_VERSION_AVAILABILITY_H_FORMAT=90200
    export PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT=binary
    export PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=YES
    export PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/PrefixHeaders"
    export PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS=NO
    export PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=/usr/local/include
    export PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME=RealmJS
    export PRODUCT_NAME=RealmJS
    export PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH=
    export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.library.static
    export PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export PROJECT=RealmJS
    export PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/DerivedSources
    export PROJECT_DIR=/Users/jouk/Workspace/react-native-todo/react-native-todo/mobileOpenAlm/node_modules/realm
    export PROJECT_FILE_PATH=/Users/jouk/Workspace/react-native-todo/react-native-todo/mobileOpenAlm/node_modules/realm/RealmJS.xcodeproj
    export PROJECT_NAME=RealmJS
    export PROJECT_TEMP_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build
    export PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates
    export PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=/usr/local/include
    export RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS=YES
    export REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES=YES
    export REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/ResourceManagerResources"
    export REZ_EXECUTABLE=YES
    export REZ_OBJECTS_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects"
    export REZ_SEARCH_PATHS="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "
    export SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES=NO
    export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT=0
    export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT=0
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk
    export SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk
    export SDK_DIR_iphonesimulator9_2=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk
    export SDK_NAME=iphonesimulator9.2
    export SDK_NAMES=iphonesimulator9.2
    export SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=13C75
    export SDK_VERSION=9.2
    export SDK_VERSION_ACTUAL=90200
    export SDK_VERSION_MAJOR=90000
    export SDK_VERSION_MINOR=200
    export SED=/usr/bin/sed
    export SEPARATE_STRIP=YES
    export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT=NO
    export SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP=YES
    export SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP=NO
    export SHALLOW_BUNDLE=NO
    export SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DerivedSources
    export SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders
    export SKIP_INSTALL=YES
    export SOURCE_ROOT=/Users/jouk/Workspace/react-native-todo/react-native-todo/mobileOpenAlm/node_modules/realm
    export SRCROOT=/Users/jouk/Workspace/react-native-todo/react-native-todo/mobileOpenAlm/node_modules/realm
    export STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING=binary
    export STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES=NO
    export STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES
    export STRIP_STYLE=debugging
    export SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES=1,2
    export SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS="iphonesimulator iphoneos"
    export SUPPORTS_TEXT_BASED_API=NO
    export SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX=ios
    export SYMROOT=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products
    export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR=/System/Library/CoreServices
    export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR=/Applications/Extras
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/Library/Documentation
    export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR=/System/Library
    export TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=1,2
    export TARGETNAME="RealmJS static"
    export TARGET_BUILD_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    export TARGET_DEVICE_MODEL=iPhone8,2
    export TARGET_DEVICE_OS_VERSION=9.2
    export TARGET_NAME="RealmJS static"
    export TARGET_TEMP_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build"
    export TEMP_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build"
    export TEMP_FILES_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build"
    export TEMP_FILE_DIR="/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS static.build"
    export TEMP_ROOT=/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates
    export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES=NO
    export UID=501
    export UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT=NO
    export USER=jouk
    export USER_APPS_DIR=/Users/jouk/Applications
    export USER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/jouk/Library
    export USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC=YES
    export USE_HEADERMAP=YES
    export USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS=NO
    export VALIDATE_PRODUCT=NO
    export VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"
    export VERBOSE_PBXCP=NO
    export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER=jouk
    export VERSION_INFO_FILE=RealmJS_vers.c
    export VERSION_INFO_STRING="\"@(#)PROGRAM:RealmJS  PROJECT:RealmJS-0.10.0\""
    export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES=NO
    export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=7C1002
    export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=0721
    export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=0700
    export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=0720
    export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH=/XPCServices
    export YACC=yacc
    export arch=x86_64
    export variant=normal
    /bin/sh -c \"/Users/jouk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobileOpenAlm-cmeqcfhepzpgbweuaddwjfottcaw/Build/Intermediates/RealmJS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS\ static.build/Script-F63FF2C51C12462600B3B8E0.sh\"

Downloading dependency: core 0.95.6
Downloading core failed. Please try again once you have an Internet connection.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not frozen, just trying to download the core libraries. If you are on a slow internet connection it may take a bit of time the first time you run, but the download is cached so this should in most cases only happen once.

Comment: No I tried many times all day long.  I solved this downloading manually and putting file in proper directory.